# mocking jquery $.ajax with jest

Tags: jquery, ajax, jestjs

Using jest how can I test a function that makes an ajax request in my jQuery app and mock its response? My app is not compiled in nodejs and runs straight in a browser. The example on the jest site https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/jquery assumes ajax function is a separate module and the whole app gets compiled with something like webpack. Here is my app:

```
(function(root) {
    "use strict";
    // if environment is node then import jquery.
    var $ = (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) ? require('jquery') : jQuery;


    function displayUser() {

        var fetchCurrentUser = function (url) {
            var xhr = $.get(url);
            $.when(xhr)
                .done(function(data) {
                    greet(data);
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                });
         };

        var greet = function(data) {
            $('#greet').text('Hello ' + data.name);
        }

        fetchCurrentUser('/my/api');

        return {
            fetchCurrentUser: fetchCurrentUser,
            greet: greet
        };
    }

    // Added this conditional so I can test in jest
    if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
        // Node
        module.exports = displayUser();
    } else {
        // Browser (root is window)
        root.displayUser = displayUser();
    }
})(this);
```

Comment: Have you looked at [jQuery Mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax)? (I'm the maintainer, btw) I don't know of anyone using it with Jest, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 10):

Mock $.ajax by using jest.fn().

```
 $.ajax = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        const fakeResponse = {
            id: 1,
            name: "All",
            value: "Dummy Data"
        };
        return Promise.resolve(fakeResponse);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

create a `__mocks__/jquery.js` in your project root to mock the jquery node_module. You can invoke functions in your mock jquery. Here's a simple code snippet:

```
const $ = {
  ajax(xhr) { return this },
  done(fn) {
    if (fn) fn();
    return this;
  },
  fail(fn) {
    if (fn) fn();
    return this;
  }
};
export default $;
```

And add some `expect` in your `fn` to test your real logic.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest setup that I have found to test files without using modules and webpack is to manually create the scripts and to add them to `window.document`. You can reference relative paths directly inside the test file using the `fs` and `path` modules. Once you have everything working you can follow [ycavatars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3897950/ycavatars) answer in order to mock the ajax calls.
Here is a simple snippet testing basic jQuery functionality, you can then add new scripts to test the functions in your own file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const jQueryFile = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../relative/path/to/jquery.js'), { encoding: 'utf-8' });
const srcFile = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../relative/path/to/yourScript.js'), { encoding: 'utf-8' });

describe('yourScript.js', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        // load the scripts
        const scriptEl = window.document.createElement('script');
        scriptEl.textContent = jQueryFile; // add jQuery file
        window.document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);

        const scriptEl2 = window.document.createElement('script');
        scriptEl2.textContent = srcFile; // add your src file
        window.document.body.appendChild(scriptEl2);
    });

    describe('jQuery behaviour', () => {
        test('creates and find elements', () => {
            const $form = $('<form><input type="text" name="query" class="ff_search_input col-xs-11" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Che cosa stai cercando?"></form>');
            const $input = $form.find('input');
            expect($input.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
        });
    });
});
```