# Mocking jQuery $() and $ functions in jest

Tags: jquery, jestjs

I have a set of tests for the functions in an ES6 class that use `$.get()`. I was able to mock `$.get()`. I'm working on testing another function in the same class that uses `$.get()` and `$(data, ownerDocument).find()`, and I haven't been able to figure out how to add mocking for the `$().find()` function.

How I'm mocking `$.get()`:

```
const jQuery = require(path/to/jquery);
jest.mock(path/to/jquery);

describe("Description", () => {
  test("Test", () => {
    // multiple tests with different mocks of $.get, so clearing
    jQuery.get.mockClear();
    jQuery.get.mockImplementation((path) => path);
    // test function that uses $.get
  });
});
```

Based on [this section](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#mocking-non-default-class-exports) from the jest docs, I tried adding mocking for the jQuery constructor by using the 2 argument version of `jest.mock`:

```
// jest.mock(path/to/jquery);
jest.mock(path/to/jquery, () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(arg1, arg2) => {
    return {
      find: () => console.log('find'); // just to see if structure works
    };
  });
});

describe("Description", () =>
  test("Test", () => {
    jQuery.get.mockClear();
    jQuery.get.mockImplementation((path) => path);

    // test function that uses $.get() and $(...).find()
  });
});
```

However, adding this broke the mocking of `$.get()` and I started getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot read property 'mockClear' of undefined
  jQuery.get.mockClear()
             ^
```

Based on [this article](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/), what I believe I'm struggling with is the right way to mock functions in the `$` namespace and the `$.fn` namespaces at the same time.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279655/how-to-mock-jquery-done-so-it-executes-correctly-with-jest) talks about how to mock `$.ajax`, and I do something like that to mock `$.get` but I'm not sure if it would help me mock `$(...).find()` as well.

Is there a way I can cleanly mock both functions I need simultaneously?

(As a side note, I'm not sure how I would create a Minimally Reproducible Example with jest, but if someone can point me to a way to do that, I'll make an MRE)

Comment: All people seem to do is mock jQuery these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, I was able to resolve this by modifying the technique in the "**Mock jQuery globally**" portion of the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279655/how-to-mock-jquery-done-so-it-executes-correctly-with-jest?noredirect=1&lq=1). My resulting mock code looks like this:

```
//__mocks__/jquery.js:

const jQ = jest.requireActual("jquery");

const get = jest.fn((path) => {
    return Promise.resolve(path);
});

const when = jest.fn((prom1, prom2, prom3, prom4) => {
    return Promise.resolve();
});

const jQuery = jQ;
jQuery.get = get;
jQuery.when = when;
exports.jQuery = jQuery;
```

As I understand it, this is essentially a pre-ES6 version of the code provided in that answer. I'm using it as follows. I don't have to worry about mocking `$().find` because the mock uses the real implementation of the `find` function.

```
// foo_ut.js

const jQuery = require("../__mocks__/jquery").jQuery;

describe("Description", () =>
  test("Test", () => {
    jQuery.get.mockClear();

    // test function that uses $.get() and $(...).find()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use JSDom to inject the JQuery package into my window.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
    const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
var window = dom.window;
var $ = require("jquery")(window);
expect($).to.be.not.undefined;
```

I also wrote an [article](https://www.the-koi.com/projects/vitest-how-to-mock-jquery/) about how i did it for vitest, should be similar to jest.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fine if you are testing

- $.method

but not

- $(selector).method

So I have added another answer for future reference.

## I want to test that $(someselector).html() has rendered

**render.js**

```js
  import jquery from 'jquery';
  export default ({selector, html}) => {
    jquery(selector).html(html)
    // other stuff here...
  }
```

---

#### PROBLEM - using methods outside jest.mock

**render.test.js**

```js
import jquery from 'jquery';

const fnHtml = jest.fn()
jest.mock('jquery', (sel) => {
  return () => ({
    html: fnHtml // This is not allowed in jest
  })
});

describe('render', () => {
  it('should invoke html method of jquery.', () => {
    const selector = '.someclass'
    const html = '<p>hello world</p>'
    const RENDERED_KEY = 'loadedHello';
    render({selector, html}) 

    expect(fnHtml).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  });
 
})
```

> error: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables

---

#### SOLUTION - Using literals outside jest.mock

**render.test.js**

```js
// import $ from '__tests__/__utils__/jquery';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import render from 'esfiles/js/util/render';

const arrHtml = [];

jest.mock('jquery', (sel) => {
  return () => ({
    html: (val) => {
      arrHtml.push(val) // This is ok
    }
  })
});

describe('render', () => {
  it('should do these things...', () => {
    const selector = '.someclass'
    const html = '<p>hello world</p>'
    render({selector, html})
    expect(arrHtml[arrHtml.length - 1]).toBe(html);
  });
 
})
```