# Jest - Unit Testing a Namespaced File

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Is it possible to write a unit test with Jest for a JavaScript file that is namespaced using the below format?

```
// utilities.js

var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.Common = MyApp.Common || {};
MyApp.Common.Utilities = new function(){
    this.getSomething = function(){  // Need to unit test this function
        return 'Something';
    }
}
```

If not, is there a better way to structure the namespaces to allow for unit testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export MyApp like following example then in utilities.test.js you can

```js
const {MyApp} = require('./utilities');

it('should work', ()=>{
  expect(MyApp.Common.Utilities.getSomething()).toEqual('something');
});
```

Comment: Is it still possible to use mocks/dependency injection with a static function like that? The function I’m using has a reference to jQuery and the Jest test fails even with a global variable defined in Jest setup.

Comment: You can mock an entire module with Jest. This answer is probably what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600296/927687